# Type error when adding two derivatives of same base class in a List

Tags: dart, casting

I have this code:

```
List<Widget> _elementsHere = _locationsRegister
        .map((e) => ShowingLocation(
              num: e.num,
              name: e.name,
              icon: e.icon,
            ))
        .toList();
```

I have specified `List<Widget>`, but if I print `_elementsHere.runtimeType.toString()` in console, I can see `List<ShowingLocation>`. In fact if I add this code:

```
_elementsHere.insert(0, Text('hello'));
```

I receive error that `Text` isn't a subtype of `ShowingLocation`, despite it's a Widget.

I want `_elementsHere` as `List<Widget>` instead of `List<ShowingLocation>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be solved by specifying the object type in the generics field of the `map` function. Since you're not specifying the type, it's being assumed to be an iterable of `ShowingLocation`.

Do this instead:

```dart
List<Widget> _elementsHere = _locationsRegister
        .map<Widget>((e) => ShowingLocation(
              num: e.num,
              name: e.name,
              icon: e.icon,
            ))
        .toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [`as`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#type-test-operators) keyword.

```
List<Widget> _elementsHere = _locationsRegister
    .map((e) => (ShowingLocation(
          num: e.num,
          name: e.name,
          icon: e.icon,
        ) as Widget))
    .toList();
```